# bcrypt loading error in windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-10, bcrypt

now I am trying to install bcrypt in windows 10, but I got an loading error whenever running webrick server as the following.

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.10-x64-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in 
`require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
```

I am using rails 4.1.5 and ruby 2.2.3. There was no problem with bcrypt when I was using windows 8.1. The ruby version was 2.1.6 when I was using windows 8.1

How can I solve this bcrypt issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It took me few hours to get this done but please feel free to share it.The root problem here is that ruby itself comes with bcrypt version 3.1.5 which is having bugs with the newer updates. However when you install or uninstall the bcrypt you are leving behind bcrypt-ruby which it always asks for first and hence all what you are doing won't go through so what to do ? 1- uninstall bcrypt and bcrypt-ruby by running these two commands:
 `gem uninstall bcrypt` 
and

```
 gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
```

2- Install it again with

```
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

In your Gemfile write

```
 gem 'bcrypt','~>3.1.11'
```

NOW as i write these lines the latest version is 3.1.11 but whatever version is updated just add it from their gem page. Run bundle install and it should work just fine.

Comment: Use `gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby` in `Gemfile` so the same happens if bundled on another machine

Answer (score 3):

In your gem file add:

```
gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

This worked for me on **Windows 10 64 Bit**.

Answer (score 2):

Try fix Gemfile

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.10', require: false
if Bundler::WINDOWS
  gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0', require: false
else
  gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.10', require: false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`gem uninstall bcrypt` and `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby` was a temporary fix, broke after *bundle install*.

### My Fix =>

**gemfile.lock:**

(Delete bcrypt from gemfile.lock)

Change devise to:

```
devise (4.4.3)
  bcrypt (~> 3.0)
```

< scroll down to DEPENDENCIES >

```
DEPENDENCIES

  bcrypt!

  devise (~> 4.3)
```

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'devise', '~> 4.3'

gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

**To commandline:**
`gem uninstall bcrypt`
`bundle install`