# Rails bcrypt load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have been getting this error when ever I have tried starting the server:

> d:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32/l
>   ib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext
>   (LoadError)

Funny thing is, I have had this error before and I solved it simply by running `gem uninstall bcrypt`,then `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby` and then by running `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby` (bcrypt gem was in the Gemfile). Now that I've added the pagination gems, the error has shown up again. I have tried a lot of possible solutions(like the ones listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469246/bcrypt-loading-error-in-windows-10) and some others).It didn't work.
Here's the Gemfile(the important bit):

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
```

Since I have a Rails 5 version,I know that these are not the final versions of the will-paginate and bootstrap-will_paginate gems and that I may not need the bootstrap-will_paginate gem.But I have tried both with the final versions(and without the bootstrap-will_paginate gem) and I have been getting the same error.Any help would be much appreciated(for the record,I work in Atom IDE on Windows 8.1).

Comment: try removing Gemfile.lock `rm -rf Gemfile.lock` and running `bundle install`

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293321/ruby-on-windows-causes-error-cannot-load-such-file-bcrypt-ext/33593911#33593911 it's because you're using Windows

Comment: Can you give me a pointer on how to properly install 'make'(or/and 'DevKit') because I don't have it and other instructions are pretty different from one user to another.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with uninstall all bcrypt gem versions with `gem uninstall bcrypt` and select option 3 (if exist) and uninstall all bcrypt-ruby gem versions with `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby` and select option 3 (if exist) then install bcrypt using `gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby` then add this line `gem 'bcrypt', platforms: :ruby` or `gem 'bcrypt', platforms: [:ruby, :x64_mingw, :mingw]` to `Gemfile`, that is it :D.