# bcrypt LoadError with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

I am having trouble finding a solution to this issue, and have tried many fixes others have ran into with no success.  I am working on the Ruby on Rails 5 Tutorial by Michael Hartl which requires using bcrypt to implement the `has_secure_password` feature.  When I run the test I get a long error message which starts with:

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x64-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in 'require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
```

I have attempted uninstalling and reinstalling bcrypt with adding `--platform=ruby` at the end and including various versions in the gemfile; `gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'`, `'bcrypt', '3.1.11', platforms: [:ruby, :x64_mingw]`, `'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7', platforms: [:ruby]` including various combinations of installing the gem file from the command line.  Leaving the gemfile hashed out while installing from the console, uninstalling and running the Bundle Install with just the gemfile link.

This is the entire Error message I am receiving when trying to access the Rails Console:

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x64-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in 'require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x64-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x64-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Bill/Documents/Sites/sample_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby23x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-.1.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:96:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in`run'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I am using Ruby version 2.3.3 with Rails version 5.1.4 running on Windows 7x64.

Any insight anyone could offer me at this point would be appreciated.

UPDATE

So after countless hours trying to solve the problem, using the gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

was what solved the problem for me.  This may not be a permanent solution, but at least it's letting me move forward!

Answer (score 2):

There are more recent solutions you may want to explore, but when I had this problem several months ago with Rails 5.0, I used the accepted answer [from this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469246/bcrypt-loading-error-in-windows-10) and it worked for me.

**Update:**
As suggested, I have added full answer in case link becomes dead.
First- Uninstall bcrypt

```
gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby
```

Then reinstall

```
gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby
```

Then in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt','~>3.1.11' # Or current version
```

Comment: Better write answer instead of referencing link, which avoids dead link problem.

Comment: @Satishakumar Awati  -Noted

Comment: So although I was able to access the Rails Console again, the error message persists when setting up a new project.  Attempted to run everything the same as suggested, but to no avail.

Comment: So after searching forums and trying numerous recommendations-  gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'  - in gemfile is what finally worked